# Looking for a word similar to metaphor or symbol or allegory

Tags: word-choice, poetry

A person is traveling dangerously fast on a rainy night with low visibility - traveling with reckless abandon in an already dangerous situation. What is the word that describes the literary sense in which this person is traveling **towards** (not spatially towards) an ambulance?

Comment: Traveling _like_ an ambulance? Hyperbole.

Comment: No, in some poetic sense the person, traveling with reckless abandonment, is traveling *towards* an ambulance. But "traveling poetically towards an ambulance" is not correct. Hopefully there is a word for this...

Comment: Do you mean it's inevitable that they will have an accident (and therefore need an ambulance)?

Comment: No, perhaps they arrive safely. What I am looking for is to fill in the phrase "traveling ? towards an ambulance" while conveying "this person was just *asking* to get in a car crash" (in the idiomatic sense of "asking for it"). At this point I could write it differently but I want to learn whether there is a word for this

Comment: Like _tempting fate_ sort of thing; _pushing the envelope_, _pushing your luck_ type driving - not guaranteed to get you into an accident every time but eventually _your number will probably come up_.

Comment: Foreshadowing? But you can't really fit that into _travelling foreshadowingly towards an ambulance_ although I suppose you can.

Comment: You'd say 'He's **heading for** ...' rather than 'He's journeying towards ...'. It's certainly a journey metaphor, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic term for usages such as OP's example is...

> [***figurative language***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/figurative+language)
>    *language that contains or uses **figures of speech**, especially metaphors.*
>
> [***figure of speech***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/figure%20of%20speech)
>    *any expressive use of language, as a metaphor, simile, personification, or antithesis, in which words are used in other than their literal sense, or in other than their ordinary locutions, in order to suggest a picture or image or for other special effect.*

Personally, I incline to the view that [***all*** language is figurative](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ctlRDJt3DfQC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=%22all%20language%20is%20figurative%22&source=bl&ots=5aDvPGweLK&sig=R50QrEJYcSi94FzDdGDbZ8YjA5A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=orcmVL2vMZLqaLzvgsgH&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22all%20language%20is%20figurative%22&f=false) - it's just *some more than others.*

Answer (score 0):

Actual prepositions are pretty limited--at, to or toward (or the suffix -ward, as in ambulance-ward). An adverb seems called for, and the first ones that occur to me are **inevitably**, or **inexorably (preferred)**. If you are writing poetry, however, you probably want to crank the rhetoric a notch or five. I would do this by use of an allusion, and the one that somewhat comically occurs to me (excuse my brain) is FDR's "rendezvous with destiny" which I would engineer to the driver's "**inexorable rendezvous with paramedicry**." See, you don't even really need the ambulance! =] ...to gurney or not to gurney, that was the question, and Schmedlap was rapidly answering it in the affirmative...

Comment: The "inexorable rendezvous with paramedicry" is beautiful but its not the ambulance, rather the traveling that I can't divest myself of - the driver's vector in some metaphysical (ie non-spatial or even temporal) space points at-or-near an ambulance. That is the crux of what I want to say. Still you helped me tease that out so you get the check :)

Comment: You have taken the hard road, but let's pursue the travel then: how about something like "driving his Chrysler Intrepid madly through the mist, like a fanatic hurtling to meet his inexorable rendezvous with destiny, with that other vehicle whose flashing lights mark the place where the impatient are made patient, and slid **into** the tailgate like flatbread into an oven"...? =]

Answer (score 0):

To **flirt** is to tease or trifle with a sense of temptation or seduction.

When you do something risky, you are figuratively posing a challenge, knowing that, with that challenge, there can be consequences (but that the consequences are by no means inexorable).

*flirt with death*, *flirt with danger*, *[flirt with disaster](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116324/)*:

> putting oneself in risky situations, where one possibly could die. For example, someone who rides a motorcycle too fast around hairpin curves could be said to be flirting with death. (from [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090830144941AAhjcoU))

*[flirt with the shark in sea](http://standingoutinmyfield.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/flirting-with-sharks/)*,

*flirt with the grim reaper*:
[image]
(from waynoblog, http://waynocartoons.blogspot.com/2012/08/weapons-of-self-destruction-number-100.html)

By extension, **to flirt with an ambulance** is figuratively to act recklessly or carelessly and in a taunting, teasing fashion, offering a temptation or challenge that the ambulance might accept.

Answer (score -1):

traveling **abstractly** towards an ambulance

Will update the answer if anything more appropriate comes along

Comment: I've never encountered such a usage. To be honest, I initially read that as ***abstractedly** (=absentmindedly)* - which would at least make sense, even if it's not the sense intended by OP.